# How to connect to TLS using Vue?

Tags: javascript, ssl, mqtt, tls1.2

I want to connect to MQTT server using Vue.
I tried something similar to what I found on Google, but failed.

- node.js example

```js
var mqtt = require('mqtt');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 8883,
  protocol: 'mqtts',
  protocolId: 'MQIsdp',
  ca: [fs.readFileSync('<path>/ca.crt')],
  key: fs.readFileSync('<path>/client.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('<path>/client.crt'),
  passphrase: 'CLIENT KEY PASSPHRASE',
  secureProtocol: 'TLSv1_method',
  protocolVersion: 3
};


var client = mqtt.connect(options);
```

- Results I wrote using a method I found on the blog

```
const option = {
      port: 48883,
      ca: [],
      key: '',
      cert: '',
      clientId: 'mqttjs_' + Math.random().toString(16).substr(2, 8),
      protocolId: 'MQTT',
      useSSL: true,
      passphrase: 'CLIENT KEY PASSPHRASE',
      secureProtocol: 'TLSv1_method',
      protocolVersion: 4,
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
    }

    axios.get('/' + 'ca.crt').then(response => {
     option.ca = [response.data]
    })

    axios.get('/' + 'client.key').then(response => {
     option.key = response.data
    })

    axios.get('/' + 'client.crt').then(response => {
     option.cert = response.data
    })
    
    
    const client = mqtt.connect('wss://url', option)
```

- error code

```
failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
WebSocket connection to 'wss://url' failed:
```

Comment: `wss://url` is temporary

Comment: All certificates need to be pre-loaded into the browser manually, you can not use dynamically loaded certs in the browser. Also the CA cert will have to be marked as trusted as it will not prompt you to trust it like a webpage. Also all the axios requests are async so will not have completed before you try and connect (not that it matters)

Comment: I am a beginner in web development
I wrote it in the vue.config.js file to load it manually.
Still getting the same error..
I want to fix the error, what should I do?
I found a similar article, but I'm still not sure.
(https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js/issues/741)
thanks for the comment

Comment: No, when I said manually I meant that the user has to do it themselves, you can NOT do it in code. Read the first comment on that issue.